# Parsing 'Step Information: Rload=100 R1=1 (Run: 2/18)' in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parsing

I receive a text from software and I want to import it to MATLAB. I faced a problem in parsing this line :

```
'Step Information: Rload=100 R1=1  (Run: 2/18)'
```

The generic structure lools like this:

```
Step information: <ParamName1>=<value> <ParamName2>=<value> .. <ParamNameNth>=<value> (Run: <current step>/<Total number of Monte Carlo steps>)
```

Since the number of parameters is not always fixed, I thought I should first ease the problem with separating the parameters names and values 'Rload=100 R1=1' from the rest and then parse it later. However, the code does not work :(

```
% Example line to parse
line = 'Step Information: Rload=100 R1=1  (Run: 2/18)';

% Parse the line using textscan
parsed_values = textscan(line, 'Step Information: %s (Run: %d/%d)');
```

This code does not work at all. It cannot even extract 2 and 18.

I tried to parse this 'Rload=100 R1=1' and I realized I cannot parse this one
Do you even use textscan?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help

```
str = 'Step Information: Rload=100 R1=1 (Run: 2/18)';
pattern = 'Rload=%d %*s R1=%d';
tokens = textscan(str, pattern);
rload = tokens{1};
r1 = tokens{2};
```

And if you can parse aalso this sample "Run: ..." you should use:

```
tokens = textscan(str, '%*s %*s %*s %*s %*s %d/%d');
run = tokens{1};
total_runs = tokens{2};
```

If you need parse all numbers respect keywords you should this code:

```
str = 'Step Information: Rload=100 R1=1 (Run: 2/18)';
pattern = 'Rload=%d %*s R1=%d %*s (Run: %d/%d)';
tokens = textscan(str, pattern);
rload_str = sprintf('Rload=%d', tokens{1});
r1_str = sprintf('R1=%d', tokens{2});
run = tokens{3};
total_runs = tokens{4};
rload = tokens{1};
r1 = tokens{2};
```